# Will styled-components ever introduce build-time CSS compilation?

Tags: styled-components

Currently there are 'known' performance losses from having CSS generated at runtime in the browser. There are other packages that offer built-time CSS generation, e.g. Linaria and Compiled. Will styled-components follow in their footsteps and give us the perfect solution?